# Install Tkinter on python 2.6 and 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, redhat, tk-toolkit

So we are trying to deploy a python module called Tkinter in a large multi-user environment under RHEL. It seems to be installed in python 2.6 but not 2.7. We tied yum install but it seems to only do it under python 2.6. How can we deploy under 2.7?

Comment: Python 2.7 should already come with Tkinter. What do you get when you do `import Tkinter`?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading Tkinter then using python 2.7 to run `python setup.py install`